# one layout.xml for multiple activities

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm new to Java and Android. I'm making an app (mostly for use by me and to get some knowledge), where I have a list view width 101 items. When I click one item, it starts a new activity, with different layout. The layout for each of the 101 items is the same, but the content is different. My question is: Can I make one .xml file for all the items, but make the content differ, based on what item is clicked?

I'll add the my code below (very experimental, and will certainly change the layout) :) Thanks for any answers!

**MainAvtivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity  extends AppCompatActivity {
ListView listView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    String[] values = new String[]{"§01. Kongle", "§02. Binders",
            "§03. Plaster", "§04. Kvitering", "§05. 'Ruter'-logo", "§06. Ølkork", "§07. Hjerteutklipp av russekort",
            "§08. Ølkork i gull", "§09. Bussbillett", "§10. Bit av et sitteunderlag", "§11. Signatur fra helsesøster",
            "§12. Skolens logo", "§13. Første bokstav", "§14. Bit av skilt", "§15. Bit av burgereske", "§16. Fjær", "§16. Bilde av Barney Stinson",
            "§17. Stoffbit", "§18. Champagnekork i gull", "§19. Billettarmbånd", "§20. Amnesty-logo", "§21. Plastskje", "§22. Mobildeksel",
            "§24. Legokloss", "§25. Tampong", "§26. Kritt", "§27. Undertøy", //Plus more
    };

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_2, android.R.id.text1, values);

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
            if (position == 0) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), fastnokkel.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            }

            if (position == 1) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), binders.class); //These classes will differ from witch item is clicked.
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            }

            if (position == 2) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), plaster.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            }

            if (position == 3) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), plaster.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            }

            if (position == 4) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), kongle.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            }

            if (position == 5) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), binders.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            }

            if (position == 6) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), kongle.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            }

            if (position == 7) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), binders.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

**Avtivity_Main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#fff"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.example.sande.listview8.MainActivity"
android:weightSum="1">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">
</ListView>
```

**Same_Layout_Different_Content.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/bildeBesk"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/kongle"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/gjenstand"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="@string/kongle"
        android:textSize="35sp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/gjoremaal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/gjenstand"
        android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:text="@string/kongleBeskrivelse"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, put all type of view in one xml file. Like in this structure :

```
<ParentLayout>
     <Type1/>
     <Type2/>
     ......
 </ParentLayout>
```

Keep visibility of all Type layout as Gone. Then when item is clicked in parent activity, pass a unique ID to identify the layout type. Then use a switch case in the second activity to activate the necessary layout.

Comment: Thanks!
I now have an xml file with two text views, both gone.
I also have this in the activity for the xml fille:
`switch (position){
            case 0:
                textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.gjenstand);
                textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                break;
            case 1:
                textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.gjoremaal);
                textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }`
whitch extends MainActivity. How can I get the value "Position" from MainActivity? Position is a parameter in a onItemClickListener

Comment: In your mainactivity's item click listener where you have written Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
Just add, i.putExtra("position", YOUR_LAYOUT_POSITION); before startActivity(i);

Comment: Thank you! I got it to work! I also replaced all my if's with a for loop, is this better than having 101 different if's, or will it make my app slow?

Comment: You can post a new question with the code. I will definitely provide you with an efficient solution.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is use a custom adapter that inherits `BaseAdapter`.

This adapter will be able to update the visual part of each cell according to the your position and show/hide elements of a single xml to do so.

For example:

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        String[] values = new String[]{"§01. Kongle", "§02. Binders",
        "§03. Plaster", "§04. Kvitering", "§05. 'Ruter'-logo", "§06. Ølkork", "§07. Hjerteutklipp av russekort",
        "§08. Ølkork i gull", "§09. Bussbillett", "§10. Bit av et sitteunderlag", "§11. Signatur fra helsesøster",
        "§12. Skolens logo", "§13. Første bokstav", "§14. Bit av skilt", "§15. Bit av burgereske", "§16. Fjær", "§16. Bilde av Barney Stinson",
        "§17. Stoffbit", "§18. Champagnekork i gull", "§19. Billettarmbånd", "§20. Amnesty-logo", "§21. Plastskje", "§22. Mobildeksel",
        "§24. Legokloss", "§25. Tampong", "§26. Kritt", "§27. Undertøy", //Plus more
        };

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return values.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return values[i];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        if (convertView == null) {
             Context context = parent.getContext();
             convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
             convertView.setTag(new ViewHolder());
        }

        // Here you set the view - set the text hide views etc... it would be beneficial to use ViewHolder pattern as well 
        ViewHolder holder = convertView.getTag();
        holder.setData(i, values[i]);
    }   
}
```